# OpenCV multiply color matrix by alpha matrix

Tags: opencv

`cv::multiply` can multiply two matrices of the same size and type, or a matrix and a scalar. However, it doesn't seem to be able to multiply matrices with different number of channels.

In my case I need to pre-multiply a 3D color matrix by an alpha matrix. Is there any way to accomplish that other than duplicating alpha channels to make it 3D as well?

Comment: I guess what you need is `cv::merge()` which would merge the alpha channel with your BGR image, It would be more clear if you provide input and output cases.

Comment: No, I don't need to add it as a fourth channel, I need a 3D image with pre-multiplied alpha, as I intend to use it for further calculations. I could `cv::merge` three copies of the alpha channel to create another 3D image to multiply by the original one, but I was hoping there's a function that does it without that overhead.

Comment: Can you share sample input and expected output ?

Comment: Iterate over the channels, and multiply each by your single channel alpha matrix.

Comment: are you looking for better performance or cleaner code or better style?!?